# Follow-up Dax Drop Duplicates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Similiar to a question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65363786/6361531),

Given, this table, I want to only keep the records where the email appears first.

| email | firstname | Lastname | Address | City | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC@XYZ.com | Scott | Johnson | A | Z | 1111 |
| ABC@XYZ.com | Bill | Johnson | B | Y | 2222 |
| ABC@XYZ.com | Ted | Smith | C | X | 3333 |
| DEF@QRP.com | Steve | Williams | D | W | 4444 |
| XYZ@LMN.com | Sam | Samford | E | U | 5555 |
| XYZ@LMN.com | David | Beals | F | V | 6666 |
| DEF@QRP.com | Stephen | Jackson | G | T | 7777 |
| TUV@DEF.com | Seven | Alberts | H | S | 8888 |

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>email</th>
      <th>firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Zip</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ABC@XYZ.com</td>
      <td>Scott</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Z</td>
      <td>1111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ABC@XYZ.com</td>
      <td>Bill</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Y</td>
      <td>2222</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ABC@XYZ.com</td>
      <td>Ted</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>3333</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DEF@QRP.com</td>
      <td>Steve</td>
      <td>Williams</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>W</td>
      <td>4444</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>XYZ@LMN.com</td>
      <td>Sam</td>
      <td>Samford</td>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>U</td>
      <td>5555</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>XYZ@LMN.com</td>
      <td>David</td>
      <td>Beals</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>V</td>
      <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DEF@QRP.com</td>
      <td>Stephen</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>G</td>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>7777</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TUV@DEF.com</td>
      <td>Seven</td>
      <td>Alberts</td>
      <td>H</td>
      <td>S</td>
      <td>8888</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Expected output table:

| email | firstname | Lastname | Address | City | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC@XYZ.com | Scott | Johnson | A | Z | 1111 |
| DEF@QRP.com | Steve | Williams | D | W | 4444 |
| XYZ@LMN.com | Sam | Samford | E | U | 5555 |
| TUV@DEF.com | Seven | Alberts | H | S | 8888 |

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>email</th>
      <th>firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Zip</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ABC@XYZ.com</td>
      <td>Scott</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Z</td>
      <td>1111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DEF@QRP.com</td>
      <td>Steve</td>
      <td>Williams</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>W</td>
      <td>4444</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>XYZ@LMN.com</td>
      <td>Sam</td>
      <td>Samford</td>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>U</td>
      <td>5555</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TUV@DEF.com</td>
      <td>Seven</td>
      <td>Alberts</td>
      <td>H</td>
      <td>S</td>
      <td>8888</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inherent ordering of a table in DAX, so in order to take the first row you need to add an index column or define an ordering on the table somehow.

For this answer, I'll assume that you've added an index column somehow (in the query editor or with a DAX calculated column).

You can create a filtered table as follows:

```
FilteredTable1 =
FILTER (
    Table1,
    Table1[Index]
        = CALCULATE ( MIN ( Table1[Index] ), ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[email] ) )
)
```

For each row in `Table1`, this checks if the index is minimal over all the rows with the same email.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we added an `Index` column with non duplicate values, it's possible to reduce the number of context transitions to only one per Email by preparing an `Indexes` table containing the indexes to be selected, and then apply this `Indexes` table as a filter using TREATAS.

```
T Index Unique = 
VAR Indexes =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        ALL( 'T Index'[Email] ),
        "MinIndex", CALCULATE( MIN( 'T Index'[Index] ) )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATETABLE( 'T Index', TREATAS( Indexes, 'T Index'[Index] ) )
```

[image: Result]

If instead we have non-unique column across the different Emails but unique per each email, like a timestamp, we can prepare a filter table containing the email and the timestamp

For instance with a `T Date` table like the following

[image: T Date table]

The calculated table becomes

```
T Date Unique = 
VAR EmailDate =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        ALL( 'T Date'[Email] ),
        "MinDate", CALCULATE( MIN( 'T Date'[Date] ) )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATETABLE( 'T Date', TREATAS( EmailDate, 'T Date'[Email], 'T Date'[Date] ) )
```

[image: T Date Unique]